# Resharper always wraps invocation parameters but should only do so for long lines

Tags: c#, resharper, word-wrap

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Premium with Resharper 8.2.0.2160. I want to wrap invocation arguments only when the line exceeds 120 characters. This is done fine in the preview area (can be demonstrated by setting Right margin to 25). This is not working in the code: The invocation arguments are wrapped always.

Here are my resharper settings:
[Resharper settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwaJ2.png)

Actual result:

```
FloatingRange floaty = new FloatingRange(
    old.From, 
    old.To, 
    old.Brackets);
```

Wanted result:

```
FloatingRange floaty = new FloatingRange(old.From, old.To, old.Brackets);
```

I've tried several options, the arguments are always wraped

What setting can I change to make it so the arguments are not wrapped when using short lines? I tried setting "Wrap invocation arguments" to "Chop if long", but this did not help.

Comment: Latest version of Resharper?  If so, maybe check here to see if it exists as a bug: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TSYSD/Quick+Start+Guide.+Searching+for+Issues  If not, logging it as bug might be a good idea: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/RSRP

Comment: Is this a question? It reads like a bug report.

Comment: @EricLippert: Now there's a question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble is that there are multiple configuration layers. One has always to check if editing the top layer.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:  You can try three things:

1. Turn on Keep Existing Line Breaks
2. Set the right margin to 250

If that doesn't do it,

3. Turn off Wrap Long Lines